# Solving a recurrence to a problem

Tags: combinatorics, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I was given a problem by a friend where I had to place blocks in a specific pattern such that each block was of area 1 but had length/width such that it fit exactly on the side of the block made until then. What I had to find out is height to width ratio after a long time. Im skipping the problem details because it's irrelevant.

I've translated the problem into math, and Ive landed with the following recurrence relation.

If $h_k, w_k$ are the height and width of the $k$-th block I place, then the following recurrence emerges:

\begin{align}
w_{2k} &= w_{2k-1} + w_{2k-2}\\
h_{2k} &= \frac1{w_{2k}} \\
\text{and}\\
h_{2k+1} &= h_{2k} + h_{2k-1} \\
w_{2k+1} &= \frac1{h_{2k+1}}\\
\end{align}

with $h_0, h_1, w_0, w_1 = 1$

And I want to explore the convergence and hence the limit of $h_k/w_k$.

I've managed to remove $w_k$ from the equations and arrived at

$$h_{2k+1} = h_{2k} + h_{2k-1}$$
and 
$$h_{2k} = \frac1{\frac1{h_{2k-1}} + \frac1{h_{2k-2}}}$$

where I have to find $$\lim_{k\to\infty} h_{2k}^2$$

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Links or references as to how such recurrences are solved is also welcome.

Comment: I must be missing a few points here. How, exactly, would you add a box of unit area on to the starting box of unit area without it being identical. Next, calculating w4 requires knowing w3, for example. Exactly where does w3 come from? How about a picture of what you are visualizing?

Answer (score 0):

We may unfold the previous term of the same parity in your recurrence, and arrive at:

$$h_{2k+1} = h_{2k} + h_{2k-1} = h_{2k} + h_{2k-2} + h_{2k-3} = h_{2k} + h_{2k-2} +\dots+ h_2$$
$$h_{2k} = \frac1{\frac1{h_{2k-1}} + \frac1{h_{2k-3}}+\dots+{1\over h_1}}$$

Quite obviously, a non-trivial limit is impossible: odd terms diverge to infinity, even terms converge to zero.

Should it be otherwise (say, $h_{2k}\underset{k\to\infty}\longrightarrow c>0$), it would follow that for $k$ large enough, $h_{2k+1}\approx c\cdot k$, hence $h_{2k}\approx{c\over{1\over2k}+{1\over2k-2}+\dots}\approx{2c\over\ln k}$, which tends to $0$, which would make a contradiction. (Yes, all that hand-waving with "$\approx$" can be made rigorous, and easily so.)

We don't even have to bother looking for the *explicit* form of $h_k$, though that's also doable.

A considerably more interesting problem would be to find $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \left(\color{red}k\cdot h_{2k}^2\right)$ (related to the [Wallis infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)), but that's another story.

Comment: So Wallis product explains why $h_{2k}\,h_{2k+1}$ seems to converge to $2/\pi$ (slowly, maybe error $O(1/k)$)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it kinda does.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a general method of solving such problems but you should almost always try to find a non-recurrent formula for your equations. After writing out a few terms of the height sequence, you may notice that $h_{2k}=\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}$ and $h_{2k+1}=\frac{(2k+1)!!}{(2k)!!}$, where n!! is the [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) of n. This is indeed true and can be quite easily proven using induction.

Now you want to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}h^2_{2n}$. We can rewrite $h_{2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}$ and then use Stirling's approximation $n! \sim n^n \cdot e^{-n} \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi n}$:
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2} \sim \frac{(2n)^{2n} \cdot e^{-2n} \cdot \sqrt{4 \pi n}}{(2^n \cdot n^n \cdot e^{-n} \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi n})^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Therefore we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h^2_{2n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\pi n} = 0$.

Comment: Using these explicit expressions, one can see that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}w_{2k}\,w_{2k+1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{h_{2k}\,h_{2k+1}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ is exactly Wallis product, so @Ivan Neretin is absolutely correct.